# Как захостить телеграм бота на yandex cloud используя .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, telegram-bot, yandex-cloud

Я новичок и недавно создал ТГ бота на C#. Теперь хочу захостить его именно на yandex cloud
т.к. мне важно наличие поддержки контейнеров. В интернете не нашёл нужных мне туториалов, заранее спасибо.

Comment: Первая ссылка гугла по запросу `yandex cloud deploy docker` дает [огроменную инструкцию](https://cloud.yandex.ru/docs/container-registry/tutorials/run-docker-on-vm) с подробными действиями развертывания докера в облаке. Плохо что-то вы искали, плохо...